# How am I passing 3 arguments error:__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, selenium

i'm trying to wait until a button appears and then click it but something goes wrong.

when I run the following code I get the following error in reference to the **first line of code after the try statement**.

*TypeError: **init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given*

what 3 args am I passing?

my code is below

```js
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import os
import time
from datetime import date

def csvWrit(data):
    print(data)
    with open(str(date.today().strftime("%B %d, %Y"))+'.csv', mode='a') as data_file:
        writer = csv.writer(data_file, delimiter=",",quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL,lineterminator="\r")
        
        writer.writerows([c.strip() for c in r.split(',')] for r in data)

        # data_writer.writerow("Parcel#")
        # for i in range(0,len(data)):   
        #     data_writer.writerow(data[i])

def main():
    url = "https://assr.parcelquest.com/impl/sdxassr" /Search.aspx
    address = "11892 paseo lucido"
    zipCode = "92128"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.getcwd()+'/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(url)
    timeout = 60
    
    #WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="heading0"]/a'))
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="frm"]/button'))
        accordion = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='frm']/button")
        accordion.click()
        
        csvWrit(parcels)
        print("data written")
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timed out waiting for agree to load")
        
   
main()
```

Comment: Post the full traceback. Don't make us guess where the problem is.

Comment: @tdelaney read again. it's 1st line after try

Comment: When I read the question, the first line after the try was a comment. And anyway, totally irrelevant. The traceback has useful information and should be posted as part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cause you are using

```
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="frm"]/button'))
```

which is wrong, try to use this :-

```
 WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='frm']/button")))
```

and it will return a web element so, you don't have to write

```
accordion = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='frm']/button")
accordion.click()
```

you can simply call `.click()`, like this :-

```
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='frm']/button"))).click()
```

Comment: May I ask what is wrong with `WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="frm"]/button'))` ?

Comment: @Prophet :- Sir an open and closing parenthesis is missing

Comment: Ah, sure. Thanks, mate. You do not have to call me sir. I feel we are partners :)

Comment: @Prophet :- I would say it's easy to gain more reputation here in this section of stackoverflow.

Comment: Not sure since most of the questions we are answering will be never seen by other users while the big points are coming from answers viewed by thousands of users in the future... Also, these points are really giving us absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Prophet :- True that, even if we get 1 dollar for each reputation, or may be a high paying job cause of this, it'd worth it. But just kind of time killing I'm doing here.

Comment: Exactly! Well, I'm sitting here as an alternative to Facebook. I hate the new policy there, banning you for each and everything. So I switched to here. At least here I'd dealing with professional questions and helping people who in most cases even don't say you "thanks".

Comment: :( you can still enjoy social life and continue here as well. This is also an addiction, but these reputation points are not actually worthy of anything. I wish wfh should end so that I can be much busy and spend less time here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="frm"]/button')))
```

I think you need to pass a tuple